# URL Containing forward slash doesn't work with NSWorkSpace

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurl, nsfilemanager, nsworkspace

There exists a file name with forward slash(/) in the system.

> For example: URL -> ~/Documents/FolderName/TestFilename/myFile.dmg.
>
> Last Path Component is -> "TestFilename/myFile.dmg"
>
> File Name is -> "TestFilename/myFile.dmg"

Now when i use the below code in my application to reveal in finder kind of stuff with the following one. It fails to does revealing in finder.

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/Documents/FolderName/TestFilename/myFile.dmg"];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] activateFileViewerSelectingURLs:@[fileURL]];
```

Now how do get this resolved for such case and make it revealing in finder for such files. I do have tried with "CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes", it doesn't seems to be work. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved if you can segregate file name and file location in your code.

Below is the sample code:

```
NSString *location = @"Users/Desktop";
NSString *fileName = @"TestFilename/myFile.dmg";
if ([fileName rangeOfString:@"/"].location != NSNotFound)
{
       fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@":"];
}

[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] selectFile:[location stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName] inFileViewerRootedAtPath:location];
```

Comment: Hemantha DS: It fails to do it for file name containing multiple forward slash